# Forcing a government official to do their job

Tags: united-states

In the wake of the United States Supreme Court [legalizing same-sex marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obergefell_v._Hodges), a number of county clerks and other officials have announced their intent to refuse to issue licenses for such marriages.  What legal remedies are there in such a situation?

Comment: Did the Supreme Court merely "legalize" such marriages, or did it _require_ all U.S. governments to issue licenses for such marriages?  And if the latter, did it leave any room for discretion on the part of subordinate governments?

Comment: @feetwet "Held: The Fourteenth Amendment requires a State to license a marriage between two people of the same sex and to recognize a marriage between two people of the same sex when their marriage was lawfully licensed and performed out-of-State."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The details depend on the state, of course. The common law thing you are looking for is a writ of mandamus -- a court order to a public official to do something (or not do something) that they are required to do under the law. Writs of mandamus were traditionally only applicable to *ministerial* tasks (i.e. things that are basically paper-shuffling where there is little to no discretion); marriage licenses are typically considered ministerial. With discretionary actions, things are much more complicated because the government official is *supposed* to have significant ability to decide what should and shouldn't be allowed; mandamus doesn't apply unless there's a *right* to the action requested. In some cases, mandamus has been replaced with other forms of judicial review, but in Alabama it is definitely still mandamus that's involved ([source](http://lawprofessors.typepad.com/civpro/2015/03/alabama-supreme-court-issues-writ-of-mandamus-enjoins-probate-judges-from-issuing-marriage-licenses-.html): mandamus is what's previously been used to *stop* issuance of licenses).

For *federal* review, which is more likely to get somewhere, the approach to use is the exact same thing that led to *DeBoer* (the case bundled into *Obergefell* that was about granting licenses), and *Perry*, and many of the other gay marriage cases: a lawsuit seeking an injunction or declaratory relief under 42 USC 1983, which allows actions in law and equity whenever anyone denies civil rights to a US citizen (or someone in the jurisdiction of the US) under color of law.

The ultimate result of this kind of suit is a federal court order to issue a marriage license, or a declaration that it's illegal to not issue the license (and so anyone who doesn't will be subject to a court order). Violating this order, like any court order, is contempt of court.